# C# Regex for custom email and domain

Tags: c#, regex

I have a razor view with an input that uses this pattern:

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+&#64mydomain.com"
```

It works great using as a front-end validation. However, how could I transform it to a Regex if I want to check on the back-end of things as well?

 My emails are constructed as follow:

**"firstname.lastname@mydomain.com"**
I have tried this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\^\\[a-zA-Z0-9\\._\\+-]\\+&#64mydomain\\.com", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, this does not work as I expect since the condition is always false.
Is there another way of getting this pattern to work with Regex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct translation of your regex to C# .NET regex will look like

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9._+-]+@mydomain\.com$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note there is no problem with `@` chars handling in .NET regexps, so `@` can be coded as `@`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9._+-]+` - one or more  (`+`) occurrences of any ASCII letter (`A-Z`, it is case insensitive due to the regex option used), digits (`0-9`), `.`, `_`, `+` and `-`
- `@mydomain\.com` - `@mydomain.com` string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew, thank you very much. It worked. I appreciate the help!